# Making a site available at http and https after installing an SSL certificate

Tags: https, http

I just had hostgator install an SSL certificate on my site. As a result, my site is only available (right now) at https://mysite.com. Based on the answer to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23163/does-https-site-needs-extra-configuration-after-installation-of-ssl-certificate), it sounds like it's possible to make it also available at http://. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: What sort of error do you get when you go to http://?

Comment: Currently I just hit a landing page. See here: http://brightagency.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. I think the problem is that [your IP address changed and it takes a while to propagate](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/ssl-certificates/important-things-you-should-know-before-installing-an-ssl-certificate#propagate).

Comment: Does that explain why my site isn't available at all at http://brightagency.net? It seems like it would either be hitting the old IP address or the new IP address, and either way, wouldn't the site come up?

Comment: And now, after the IP change propagated, I see that both are available.